# Too many arguments, expected arguments "command" "config"

Tags: data-migration

```
Too many arguments, expected arguments "command" "config".
```

migrate:settings [-r|--reset] [-a|--auto] [--] **strong text**

I am getting the above error on migration settings command.
php bin/magento migrate:settings --reset vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/Magento 1.9.2.4/config.xml
I have made changes in config  file but still the command is not executing

Comment: it is work fine??

Comment: no i posted the command was incorrect. I posted the correct command below check it

Comment: okay but new posted command is work or not??

Comment: it is posted already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php bin/magento migrate:settings --reset vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.2.4/config.xm
the command was incorrect.so i use the above command and it worked